# Jquery toggleclass and click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button

```
<button id="expansion" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
    stuff
</button>
```

and when i click it, i want this to either appear or disappear

```
<div class="container-fluid" >
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div style="padding:0 7%;line-height:30px;text-align:justify;" id="expandable" class="dis">
                            <p>lol</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my jquery function. but when i click the button, nothing happens.

```
$("#expansion").click(function(){
        $("#expandable").toggleClass("dis");
    });
```

class "dis" is just display:none;

Comment: why not just `$("#expandable").toggle()`?

Comment: how does it know what to toggle? and it doesn't work :(

Comment: [Ki v2](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6885145/ki-v2) got it.  `toggle()` just shows/hides whatever is returned by the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the `.` in declaration of class and use `toggle` instead of `toggleClass`

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bjv25cbq/) is working fiddle for you.

**HTML**

```
<button id="expansion" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
    stuff
</button>

<div class="container-fluid" >
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div style="padding:0 7%;line-height:30px;text-align:justify;" id="expandable" class="dis">
                            <p>lol</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#expansion").click(function(){
    $("#expandable").toggle(".dis");
});
```

**CSS**

```
 .dis{
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assing a height to the element you want to click cuz it seems invisible.

Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g72nr1sp/

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid" >
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12" id="expansion" style="height:20px;">
              <div style="padding:0 7%;line-height:30px;text-align:justify;" id="expandable" class="dis">
                                         <p>lol</p>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dis {
    display:none;
}
#expansion{
    background-color:lime;
    height:20px;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#expansion").click(function(){
        $("#expandable").toggleClass("dis");
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

include jquery and toggle all are working fine after that you can hide and show

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("#expansion").click(function(){
    $("#expandable").toggle();});});
```